# Вывод атрибутов в Magento

Tags: magento, themes, атрибуты

Создал в админке атрибут, поместил его в свой сет,перед этим его создав этот сет.не отображается.ладно бы только в моей теме не отображалось,а то и базовая никак не реагирует и rwd. как отобразить его?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том, что атрибут должен быть отмечен как видимый (visible).

Comment: @Abyx я решил просто ответить на свой вопрос,что бы мало ли кто то будет искать такое же

Comment: @Abyx и правда, будьте внимательнее при проверке.